# Find a symmetric line perpendicular to a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the line $m$ given by parametric equations $$x=s+2, y=7-s, z=s-1 $$ and consider the plane $$\pi :9x-5y-4=0.$$ Determine the symmetric equation of the line $l$ that is perpendicular to the plane $\pi$, also, the line $l$ contains the point of $m$.

I tried to solve this and ended up getting $l:\frac{x-7/2}{9}=\frac{y-11/2}{-5};z=\frac{1}{2}$, but as far as I know, such answer is not correct. Any help is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by symmetric equation.

Comment: If you mean to say that the line $l$ contains the point of the line $m$ which lies on the plane $\pi$, then your answer is correct.